# JOGL efficient render loop

Tags: java, implementation, jogl, game-loop

I am new to JOGL and I am trying to figure out how to make a render loop with it... I know that there is the animator and FPS animator classes that I can use, but they seem fairly restrictive. I have written a few render loops in the past that I like a lot better that I would rather use but I can't seem to properly implement it with JOGL's GLEventListener Class.

Here is my render loop (and the class it comes in)

```
package com.richardkase.game;

public class Game implements Runnable {

public final String TITLE = "Test Game";

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

private FPSCounter fps;


////// Constructor //////

public Game() {

    fps = new FPSCounter(150, 60);
}


////// Game Loop //////

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        fps.findDeltas();

        // this executes at "the second argument" of fps times a second
        if (fps.checkTickDelta())
            tick();

        // this executes at "the first argument" of fps times a second
        if (fps.checkFrameDelta())
            render();

        // this code executes once a second
        fps.checkPassingSecond();
    }
}


////// Tick Methods //////

private void tick() {
    long before = System.nanoTime();
    // code goes here

    fps.tick(before);
}


////// Render Methods //////

private void render() {
    long before = System.nanoTime();
    // code goes here

    fps.render(before);
}



////// Thread Methods //////

private synchronized void start() {
    if (running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

private synchronized void stop() {
    if (!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.exit(1);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


///////// Main Method //////////

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.TITLE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}
}
```

here is FPSCounter class just for reference, all it does is keep track of time to make sure everything executes when it is suppose to

```
public class FPSCounter {

private long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

private double tickRate;
private double tickCheck;
private double tickDelta;

private double frameRate;
private double frameCheck;
private double frameDelta;

private int updates;
private int frames;
private long timer;

private long nanosPerFrame;
private long nanosPerUpdate;


////// Constructor ///////

public FPSCounter(double frameRate, double tickRate) {

    this.frameRate = frameRate;
    frameCheck = 1_000_000_000 / this.frameRate;
    frameDelta = 0;

    this.tickRate = tickRate;
    tickCheck = 1_000_000_000 / this.tickRate;
    tickDelta = 0;

    updates = 0;
    frames = 0;
    timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

}


////// find delta //////

public void findDeltas() {
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    tickDelta += now - lastTime;
    frameDelta += now - lastTime;
    lastTime = now;
}


////// Delta Check //////

public boolean checkTickDelta() {
    if (tickDelta >= tickCheck)  {
        tickDelta = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkFrameDelta() {
    if (frameDelta >= frameCheck)  {
        frameDelta = 0;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


////// Second Check //////

public void checkPassingSecond() {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
        System.out.println(updates + " updates, fps is " + frames);
        timer += 1000;
        frames = 0;
        updates = 0;
    }
}


////// Game Loop Methods ///////

public void render(long before) {
    long after = System.nanoTime();
    nanosPerFrame = after - before;
    frames++;
}

public void tick(long before) {
    long after = System.nanoTime();
    nanosPerUpdate = after - before;
    updates++;
}
}
```

how should I add the actual content to this game loop? should I have this class also extend GLEventListener or have a reference to a class that extends it? Or is there a more efficient way of doing it with the animator class that gives me the this kind of control that I am overlooking?

any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

EDIT:

I should also add that I am very new to JOGL, found out about it a few days ago because I was trying to render things in 3d, so I barely know more than the profile system in JOGL... explainations are GREATLY appreciated!

I think I should layout what I'm looking for here. I need a rendering loop that renders in a similar way above, where the game updates its state at one rate, and redraws all the graphics at another rate.

Comment: Your source code is overcomplicated and you should look at the Java documentation of our APIs instead of reinventing (badly) the wheel. There is already some methods to count FPS and the animators aren't restrictive. When you use our features, we're responsible for the potential bugs. When you replace them by your own code, it becomes your problem. There is a reason why JOGL contains some classes like Animator and GLEventListener, it handles smartly the full life cycle of the drawables.

Comment: Instead of asking for explanations, maybe you should read a bit more our wiki, especially this article about the profiles: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html If you use some poor code to start your project, don't be surprised of breaking the synchronization with the GPU and waste 30% of the framerate... If you just want to have a single update per frame, just call your update method in GLEventListener.display(). Creating a game is already complicated enough. If you complicate the few very simple things, I don't imagine how you will complicate the rest :s

Comment: javax.media.opengl.FPSCounter is implemented by all animators ;) http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/FPSCounter.html

Comment: @gouessej sorry but I'm missing why mine is so complicated, If I switch over to the plain Animator (because you said FPSAnimator can be inconsistent) then how should I use it to have better control. So if I want to get the fps the animator is running at so I could display it or something, or change the target framerate while its running or something like that (and I don't want to force v-sych to be used, it always slows down games on my computers) how should I do that, is there a tutorial on how to do use this or a wiki that tells how it is implemented not just the methods available?

Comment: the last two things you posted didn't help much, I understand the profile system fine, and the wiki is only helpful if you already know how it works and you just need to remember the name of a method or something...

Comment: just start with what you understand until you feel comfortable with it. then later on, you can start improving the performance and try to hack your code in your own pace... don't let people push you around with "that's not the right way" or "my code is better". the only code that's "better" is the code that you can understand and to be able to understand it, play around with less complicated stuff ;) and in time, i am sure you will do amazing things with opengl

Comment: @Ubica hahaha thanks for the inspirational pep talk! But I really do want to use the most efficient code, and want to know how to implement things in the most efficient way. In fact the reason why I used my class over the animator is because it doesn't seem like the animator class gives you control over updating and displaying separately. if you really can do it with the animator I would like to know but I guess that isn't an option... anyway thanks for help, and if gouessej would like to tell me how I would love to learn that as well...

Comment: At first, disabling the vertical synchronization is only useful in benchmarking code and can often cause screen tearing. Yes it caps the framerate but you can add an option into your game to modify it when you want. I'm sorry to contradict Ubica but I'm responsible for engine support in the JogAmp community, there are some best practices to respect not to bother newbies but to help them to avoid writing useless buggy code. I have created my own first person shooter, I already know how to write efficient code.

Comment: Are you sure that you will get better performance by updating and displaying separately in your particular case? If you're sure you will, keep in mind that you will have to use proper synchronization so that only the rendering thread will access your data during the rendering. Moreover, if you really want to write efficient code, use NEWT: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html I advise you to contact Mark on our IRC channel, he separates the updates and the render calls in his projects, he knows exactly what to do: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=jogamp

Comment: I'm sorry to blame Ubica but unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't the panacea, it's not the best place to get pertinent answers to JOGL specific questions. I've seen some very poor code posted here, for example a call of Thread.sleep() in GLEventListener.display(), examples to create a full screen window that doesn't work under GNU Linux, tons of examples that store GL instances into fields whereas they can become invalid, ... I'm peremptory but educating the developers about JogAmp is our (JogAmp community) responsibility. "better" code = less useless bug reports = much time to improve JOGL :)

Comment: I'm just starting out with game development, so for right now I'm just running the whole thing in one thread, and this project is really just for me to define 3D geometry to be used later, that way I can make an object and keep track of the object in 3d space. when it comes time to make the "finished" game loop I'll check out NEWT to see if it is worth and look at that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I started with JOGL... It is pretty straightforward and self-explanatory, but if requested, I can explain the code in detail ;)

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

public class OpenGLMain implements GLEventListener { 

    private static FPSAnimator animator;
    private static int width;
    private static int height;
    private static GL2 gl;
    public static Rectangle screenSize;
    public static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getMaximum(true);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(glprofile);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);

        screenSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
        width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

        frame = new JFrame("Frame name");
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        animator = new FPSAnimator(25);
        animator.add(canvas);
        animator.start();

        canvas.addGLEventListener(new OpenGLMain());
        canvas.requestFocus();

        Listeners.keyClicks(canvas);
        Listeners.mouseMovement(canvas);
        Listeners.mouseClicks(canvas);
        Listeners.mouseScrolled(canvas);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        update();
        render(drawable);
    }

    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        Scenes.init(drawable, gl);
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    }

    private void update() {
        Scenes.update();
    }

    private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        Scenes.render(drawable);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class OpenGLMain implements GLEventListener {
```

This line allows you to implement GLEvents that come with JOGL

---

```
GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getMaximum(true);
GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(glprofile);
GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
```

This will get the maximum possible openGL context to use in the canvas

---

```
screenSize = GraphicsEnvironment
    .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
    .getMaximumWindowBounds();
width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
```

Maximum window bounds will give you usable desktop space, but you could just set width and height to any other size you want...

---

```
frame = new JFrame("Frame name");
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
frame.setSize(width, height);
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This is the JFrame that will hold the OpenGL canvas. You can set it up any way you like :)

---

```
animator = new FPSAnimator(25);
animator.add(canvas);
animator.start();
```

This creates animator with framerate of 25fps, connects it to the canvas and starts the animator thread

---

```
canvas.addGLEventListener(new OpenGLMain());
canvas.requestFocus();
```

This will add a GLEvent listener to the newly created instance of your class, but I guess this is the point at which you would insert a separate GLEventListener class

---

```
Listeners.keyClicks(canvas);
Listeners.mouseMovement(canvas);
Listeners.mouseClicks(canvas);
Listeners.mouseScrolled(canvas);
```

This is my way of starting listeners for keys, mouse movement, clicks and scrolls... it is located in a separate static class

---

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

This is just a listener for window closing event...

---

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    update();
    render(drawable);
}
```

Here is where the main loop happens... I've split it up into `update();` and `render();` methods, so that everything gets updated before it gets rendered.

---

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    Scenes.init(drawable, gl);
}
```

The init method that happens before rendering... I have a separate static class Scenes, where I create layers and logical structure of the scenes to draw on canvas.

Comment: yea can you explain this? commenting would be good but a summary of how it works would be even better thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer ;) sorry for late response, I'm sorta working on something :)

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, but I figured it out on my own a few hours ago... And this actually helps me out in a different way, Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: no problem... the best way to learn is to find your own way of understanding concepts ;)

Comment: FPSAnimator has an inconsistent behaviour across platforms, rather use a plain animator and enable vertical synchronization. Moreover, use Swing and AWT only if you really need them, otherwise use NEWT.